# An integrated editor for HTML documents that works in real time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The Concept: I am developing a web app that will be able to produce content (Document) for the user based on input provided by the user through the user's dashboard. In addition, the user must be able to modify the created HTML document to meet his or her needs.

Problem: I'm looking for a real-time HTML editor (live composer) because the users here aren't tech-savvy, so that when the user can click on various sections of the document it can be edited to his or her liking.

Efforts include: I scanned the web but couldn't find a solution to my problem; what I did find were WYSIWYG editors such as `CKeditor`.

Comment: CKeditor can be very powerful when you dig into features like custom html templates you can add to toolbar, using it inline, image management etc. What sort of features are you looking for that it doesn't provide?

Comment: I think I found a trick. Thank you